# Kubernetes networking issue bridged adapter

Tags: networking, vagrant, kubeadm

I am working on setting up a multi-node, multi hardware server Kubernetes Cluster.
I am using Calico and Kubeadm.

So I am trying to use a bridge adapter within VMS to allow visibility over the network to a remote server using promiscuous mode and a static IP address.

The issue is when the VM is created, **I cannot ping into it**.

I have used to initialize kubeadm:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address="192.168.2.50" --apiserver-cert-extra-sans="192.168.2.50" --node-name master --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

I am asking if there's an additional networking config to enable ping the Vms successfully.

This is the code I've used into the vagrantfile:

```
      s.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|

        v.name = vM_NAME
        v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictype3', 'Am79C973']
        v.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nicpromisc3', 'allow-all']
        v.memory = 2048
        v.gui = false

      end

      s.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.2.#{i + m - 1}",# netmask: "255.255.255.0",

      auto_config: true,
      virtualbox__intnet: "k8s-net"


      s.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM", ip: "192.168.2.#{i + m -1}",# netmask: "255.255.255.0",

      auto_config: true
```

Thank you.

Comment: While doing kubeadm init add the PUBLIC IP and PORT as part of --control-plane-endpoint parameter. <br>
```sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.2.50 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=192.168.2.50 **--control-plane-endpoint=192.168.2.20** --node-name master --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing kubeadm init add the PUBLIC IP and PORT as part of **--control-plane-endpoint** parameter.

```
sudo kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=x.x.x.x --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=x.x.x.x **--control-plane-endpoint=y.y.y.y** --node-name master --pod-network-cidr=z.z.z.z/16
```

Worker nodes over the network can join the master node using the new generated join-command.